# Changing CSS with JS and saving change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a page that lets the user chose colours and various elements on the page will adopt the new colour. For example boxes to show the colour scheme selected. I've been using the code `$('').css('background_colour',.....)` and it works great.

The problem I have now is I made an example webpage which should use these various colours in the relevant sections of the page. For example, main text, background colour, etc. I can't use what I have been doing because none of the changes save and when I click the link that opens the example page it only shows the original colours I put in its CSS file. I figured the method I'm using doesn't isn't actually rewritting the CSS file because when I reload the page where the user selects colours every goes back to default.

If anyone can point me to places to read or suggest the best approach to changing the CSS file that is for a different page AND allows for those changes to be saved I would really help me out.

Hope my description makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either cookies or html5 localstorage to store client preferences for your website.
It's plenty of different libraries on the Internet which can help you in this task.

#### Cookies libraries

https://code.google.com/p/cookies/

https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies

#### Localstorage library

http://www.jstorage.info/

I would suggest cookies if you need to read user preferences from your server side.

Otherwise you can go for localstorage.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'd go with cookies, though (or use a polyfill, just to make sure). Check out the localStorage info section at http://html5please.com/

Comment: If you use cookies, users will lost their changes too if they clear their browser data

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use colors in relevant pages, you have to save your color change events in database or in sessions or in cookies.
Otherwise you can not save changes. Because web page is rendered again when you refresh the page.